# How to reduce Javascript repetition

Tags: javascript, html, button, repeat, cs50

I have been working on an online calculator in the CS50 IDE. Everything is working fine so far, although I am bothered by how much repetition there is. My code is below:

```js
document.querySelector("#one").onclick = function() {
  let expression = document.querySelector("#expression");
  if (Number(expression.innerHTML) == 0) {
    expression.innerHTML = 1;
  } else {
    expression.innerHTML += 1;
  }
}
document.querySelector("#two").onclick = function() {
  let expression = document.querySelector("#expression");
  if (Number(expression.innerHTML) == 0) {
    expression.innerHTML = 2;
  } else {
    expression.innerHTML += 2;
  }
}
document.querySelector("#three").onclick = function() {
  let expression = document.querySelector("#expression");
  if (Number(expression.innerHTML) == 0) {
    expression.innerHTML = 3;
  } else {
    expression.innerHTML += 3;
  }
}
document.querySelector("#four").onclick = function() {
  let expression = document.querySelector("#expression");
  if (Number(expression.innerHTML) == 0) {
    expression.innerHTML = 4;
  } else {
    expression.innerHTML += 4;
  }
}
document.querySelector("#five").onclick = function() {
  let expression = document.querySelector("#expression");
  if (Number(expression.innerHTML) == 0) {
    expression.innerHTML = 5;
  } else {
    expression.innerHTML += 5;
  }
}
document.querySelector("#six").onclick = function() {
  let expression = document.querySelector("#expression");
  if (Number(expression.innerHTML) == 0) {
    expression.innerHTML = 6;
  } else {
    expression.innerHTML += 6;
  }
}
document.querySelector("#seven").onclick = function() {
  let expression = document.querySelector("#expression");
  if (Number(expression.innerHTML) == 0) {
    expression.innerHTML = 7;
  } else {
    expression.innerHTML += 7;
  }
}
document.querySelector("#eight").onclick = function() {
  let expression = document.querySelector("#expression");
  if (Number(expression.innerHTML) == 0) {
    expression.innerHTML = 8;
  } else {
    expression.innerHTML += 8;
  }
}
document.querySelector("#nine").onclick = function() {
  let expression = document.querySelector("#expression");
  if (Number(expression.innerHTML) == 0) {
    expression.innerHTML = 9;
  } else {
    expression.innerHTML += 9;
  }
}
document.querySelector("#zero").onclick = function() {
  let expression = document.querySelector("#expression");
  if (Number(expression.innerHTML) == 0) {
    expression.innerHTML = 0;
  } else {
    expression.innerHTML += 0;
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 39.5%;
  top: 6.25%;
  -ms-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  transform: translate(0%, -40%);
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center;" id="expression">0</div>
<div style="text-align: center; border: 3px solid blue; height: 30px; width: 300px; margin: 0 auto;">
  <div class="center">
    <button id="one">1</button>
    <button id="two">2</button>
    <button id="three">3</button>
    <button id="four">4</button>
    <button id="five">5</button>
    <button id="six">6</button>
    <button id="seven">7</button>
    <button id="eight">8</button>
    <button id="nine">9</button>
    <button id="zero">0</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the script section of the body is basically a giant mess of copy-pasting. Is there any way for me to simplify this code so I wouldn't have to repeat Javascript code while keeping the same functionality?

Comment: You can just use a function where you can send in the parameter as a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of selecting the buttons individually by ID, select by the button element or using a common class on all buttons.  Then apply the listener to all of them.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("#buttons button");
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    let expression = document.querySelector("#expression");
    if (Number(expression.innerHTML) == 0) {
      expression.innerHTML = buttons[i].textContent;
    } else {
      expression.innerHTML += buttons[i].textContent;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center;" id="expression">0</div>
<div class="center" id="buttons">
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>4</button>
  <button>5</button>
  <button>6</button>
  <button>7</button>
  <button>8</button>
  <button>9</button>
  <button>0</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This one worked for me. I used a class instead of selecting all buttons since there will be other kinds of buttons later on.

Answer (score 2):

You should create just one function that takes the number as a parameter:

```
<button id="one" onClick="add(1)">1</button>
<script>
    function add(num) {
        // etc
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add click listener to parent and listen its children click based on that show expression

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Calculator</title>
        <style>
           
         
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="text-align: center;" id="expression">0</div>
        <div style="text-align: center; border: 3px solid blue; height: 30px; width: 300px; margin: 0 auto;">
            <div class="center">
                <button id="one">1</button>
                <button id="two">2</button>
                <button id="three">3</button>
                <button id="four">4</button>
                <button id="five">5</button>
                <button id="six">6</button>
                <button id="seven">7</button>
                <button id="eight">8</button>
                <button id="nine">9</button>
                <button id="zero">0</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            document.querySelector(".center").onclick = function(event) {
                  let expression = document.querySelector("#expression");
                if(event.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
                  const text = event.target.textContent;
                  if(expression.textContent == 0) {
                     expression.innerHTML = text;
                  } else {
                     expression.innerHTML += text;
                  }
                }
      
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```